# jQuery - Value in Function

Tags: jquery, arrays, function

My array:

```
array.name = "Thiago";  
array.date = "01/01/1990";
```

I want a function like this:

```
function myFunc( array, fieldToCompare, valueToCompare  )
{
    if( array.fieldToCompare == "Thiago" )
        alert(true);
}

myFunc( myArray, name, "Thiago" );
```

is it possible?

Comment: your array is object not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use brackets notation to access property by variable:

```
function myFunc( array, fieldToCompare, valueToCompare  )
{
    if( array[fieldToCompare] == "Thiago" )
        alert(true);
}
```

And wrap `name` in quotes:

```
myFunc( myArray, 'name', "Thiago" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array(which is not an array instead an object) is like this

```
var myarray = [
  { "name": "bob", "date": "01/01/1990" },
  { "name": "john", "date": "02/01/1990" },
  { "name": "larry", "date": "03/01/1990" }
];
```

Use this method

```
function myFunc( arr, fieldToCompare, valueToCompare )
{
    if(fieldToCompare=='name')
    {
        arr.map(function (myObj) {
        if (myObj.name == valueToCompare) {
          alert('name : '+ myObj.name + ' date : '+ myObj.date);
        } else {
            return null;
         }
       });
    }
    else {
        arr.map(function (myObj) {
        if (myObj.date == valueToCompare) {
          alert('name : '+ myObj.name + ' date : '+ myObj.date);
        } else {
            return null;
         }
       });
    }        
}
```

**Demo** : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/5sr6pvLL/2/)